# Use Populate method with datatables in Node js + Mongo DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, datatable

I am working with this [code link](https://blog.dephyned.com/2014/01/24/using-jquery-datatables-with-nodejs-and-mongodb-using-mongoose-datatables/). Datatable is created but how can i use populate method with query. As according to provide code:

```
exports.getDataForDataTable = function getData (request, response)
{
  MyModel.dataTable(request.query, function (err, data) {
    response.send(data);
  });
};
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598712/how-should-i-properly-use-populate-with-mongoose

Comment: I am using datatable so i need syntax with datatable. Populate normally works but how it works with datatable syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add populate field in the request.query object

```
exports.getDataForDataTable = function getData (request, response)
{
   request.query.populate = 'Model';
   MyModel.dataTable(request.query, function (err, data) {
   response.send(data);
});
};
```

Comment: After apply this search is not working for other columns, it is only work on first column.

Comment: Fields must be defined in the search object fields: ['username'] in which you want to search. Can you conosle.log you request.query object and paste it here so i can see what is wrong.

Comment: conditions: { '$and': [ { '$or': [ { title: { '$in': [ /2/i ] } } ] } ] }, This condition is generated only

Comment: It must consists of other columns also.

Comment: search: { value: '', regex: 'false' }, this is coming when i console query object for search.

Comment: @Anshul hey did you get any solution about search with populate ?